# RabbitMQ Exchange not getting created using Spring-Cloud-Stream

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I am new to Java Spring Cloud. I am trying to publish a message to an exchange using RabbitMQ. But once i run my java application, i do not see any Exchange being created. I am not getting any error too. What am i missing ?

I tried setting disk free limit to 200MB which was initially set to 50MB but still noticed no change.

The below is my code snippet for the controller class ::

```
public class AppointmentController {

private static final Logger 
   logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppointmentController.class);
    @Autowired
    AppointmentSender sender;

    @PostMapping("/appointment-management-service/appointments")
    public void bookAppointment(@RequestBody AppointmentEvent 
              appointmentEvent) 
    {
       logger.info("Appointment request received {}",appointmentEvent);
       appointmentEvent.setStatus(AppointmentStatus.INITIATED);
       boolean isSent = sender.send(appointmentEvent);
       logger.info("Appointment booking initiated {}",isSent);

     }

}
```

The below is my code snippet for the Message Sender class ::

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class AppointmentSender {

@Autowired
private Source source;

public boolean send(AppointmentEvent appointmentEvent) {
      return this.source.output().
      send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(appointmentEvent).build());
}

}
```

The below is the application.properties file

```
spring.application.name=appointment-management-service
server.port=8000
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.host=127.0.0.1
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
spring.rabbitmq.broker-url=tcp://127.0.0.1:5672
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host= /
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=appointments-exchange
```

The below is pom.xml ::

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.microservices</groupId>
<artifactId>appointmentmanagementsystem</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>appointmentmanagementsystem</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                 <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

An exchange with the name "appointments-exchange" is not getting created.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your properties into a new Boot project and it worked fine.

[image]

Does your guest user have admin permissions?

Try enabling DEBUG logging to see if there are any clues.

Comment: Is the `AppointmentSender` in a package scanned by boot? Normally you would put the `@EnableBinding` alongside the `@SpringBootApplication` on the application class.

Comment: Thanks Gary !
I checked the user permissions via below command for guest user. It is that of administrator.
>rabbitmqctl list_user_permissions guest
Listing permissions for user "guest" ...
vhost   configure       write   read
/       .*      .*      .*


Also checked the rabbitmq log file (rabbit@DESKTOP-3S8M6IV.log).Log Snippet as below ::

Any idea what else could have been missed ?

Comment: Nothing more I can think of; when I enable DEBUG logging, I see `DEBUG 16436 --- [           main] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : declaring Exchange 'appointments-exchange'`. if you post your project someplace, I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have uploaded my code at below location ::
https://github.com/amdhawan-pers/SpringCloudStreamBasics

Comment: I haven't figured out why, yet, but you somehow have the `TestSupportBinder` on the main classpath and so that binder is being used instead of Rabbit. You have it in test scope so it shouldn't be on the classpath. I even commented it out but it's still there somehow; weird; eclipse doesn't show it in the dependency hierarchy.

Comment: Still not sure what's going on, but I solved it by removing the `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` dependency from the `messaging-common` project. ` declaring Exchange 'appointments-request'`. It's probably eclipse not honoring the test scope for dependent projects. That messaging-common project looks like it shouldn't be a boot app anyway and should be installed into the maven local repo.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary ! I removed it too and it is working now !